# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous how to fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am getting the error File "C:/Users/user/tensorEnv/project.py", line 27, in 
    if N <= 100 :
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() how to fix this problem

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
r3=np.arange(1.11,10,0.1)
r1=1
r2=1.1
k=5
R1cond=3.36*10**(-3)
R2cond=(1/N)*(0.0727-(0.08/r3))
Rconv=(0.004)/(r3**2)
Rtotal=Rconv+R1cond+R2cond
qloss=975/Rtotal
t=176
Q=qloss*t
L0=[]
L0.append(Q)
L0=[x*10**(-3) for x in L0]
#E is the price of EDL in LBP/NW.h
#Eel is the electric price to pay
#t is the time of working hours of the furnace 22 business days
#E=Eel*qloss*t
L=[]
L1=[]
L2=[]
L3=[]
L4=[]
for N in L0:
        if N <= 100 :
                L.append(35*N)
        if N <= 300 and N > 100:
                L1.append( 55*N)
        if N <=400 and N > 300:
                L2.append(80*N)
        if N <= 500 and N > 400:
                L3.append(120*N)
        if N > 500 :
                L4.append(200*N)
plt.plot(L)
plt.plot(L1)
plt.plot(L2)
plt.plot(L3)
plt.plot(L4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take a moment and [edit] to include the full traceback(s) of your errors

Comment: In the plotting error, you're trying to plot with a list of 100 x values (`r3`) and a single y value (`R1cond`), and matplotlib doesn't know how to handle that. What is your expected output from `plt.plot(r3,R1cond...`?

Comment: a plot of the conduction, convection and total resistance versus the thickness of the insulation

Comment: Yes, but specifically in the line mentioned, what would that first plot look like, with 100 values vs a single value? Should it be a flat line, a single point? The value of `R1cond` doesn't change or repeat with the values of `r3` so it's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: i solved this part i was plotting a straight line for R1cond and the others are in function of r3 and i think that python was expected to plot R1 in function of x i fixed it,can u help me with the second part?

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full error traceback so that we can understand where the issue is occurring. Assuming it's on the lines that deal with `if Q <=..." please also provide the type and shape of `Q`, what you expect it to be and what you expect the output to be

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous